# IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2, Gradle 4.9, External Library not referenced in classpath

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have the following build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.foo:cordapp-settlement:0.1"
    ...
}
```

In External Libraries in my project I can see (which is located in my local maven repo)

```
External Libraries
    <1.8> /Library/Java/...
    ...
    Gradle: com.foo:cordapp-settlement:0.1
      cordapp-settlement-0.1.jar
        com.foo.analytics
          state
            SettlementInstruction
```

However in the IDE Editor I have the following

```
import com.foo.analytics.state.SettlementInstruction
           ^ Unresolved Reference foo
```

I've tried all of the various prescribed remedies: Invalidate Cache, delete .idea directory, reimport project. How do I fix this?

Note: This builds fine on the command line, i.e. no errors

```
 ./gradlew build
 ...
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
 5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

Comment: Can you build/run it from IDE? What is your OS? Try re-import as Gradle project project from File | New | Project from existing sources. Also try re-install IDE form https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?